# Creating a new SharedPreferences object each time for reading config vars?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is it acceptable to create a new SharedPreferences object everywhere in code that we want to read config vars?

```
SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

I have such code in several methods and classes, and every time a method is called the same code is executed again and again to get just another instance of a SharedPreferences object.

I think I can reduce all of these into one instantiation only, storing that SharedPreferences object into some class var/field and then using the object stored in that var in every other place (Create once and use many times). Probably I can store it in a static field of a separate class dedicated to this purpose and then use that in every other class.

What do u suggest and why?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't use a static instance of my `SharedPreferences` in any of my applications. I always get it as you do `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` and use in that specific method.

If you're accessing too frequently in a specific method to your prefs, perhaps you should reconsider whether it's a good use or not. If that information you're constantly getting from prefs is that frequently needed, why don't you keep it in memory and load from prefs just when it's not there? I'd definitely go for that.

Just for curiosity if you wanna see an example of what `getSharedPreferences` method does internally take a look at [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#L329).

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to those variables in an activity then you take care of that when the activity is created and then save the values as variables. Then if you need to use it in methods within that activity then you'll have easy access to them.

If a separate class needs those values then just pass those in as parameters. This will cut down the number of times that you have to "run the same code."

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton extending the `Application` class and instantiate the `sharedPreferences` in that. And provide `public static` access to it.

Like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
     private static SharedPreferences prefs;
     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     }

     public static SharedPreferences getSharedPref(){
          return prefs;
     }
}
```